# IP address directly into omnibar of chrome takes me to a different website than what shows up when I tracert

Tags: dns

When I use tracert facebook.com from my command prompt, I get back the IP address of 157.240.18.35

When I put 157.240.18.35 into the omnibar, it then takes me straight to Facebook.

Now, when I use tracert rot13.com , it brings me back the IP address of 216.92.143.231

When I put 216.92.143.231 into the omnibar, it brings me to travisjhicks.com , which looks like a totally different website.

Why is this? I am studying networking right now and apologize if this is the incorrect forum, I am new to Stackexchange and forums in general. I usually just find an answer on Google, but I couldn't with this one.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a shortage of IP(v4) addresses the http and https protocols have a mechanism to host multiple websites on a single IP address.

In the case of 216.92.143.231, the default address is "travishicks.com".  There may be a specific reason for this, but most likely its fairly random and represents the first valid entry in web server config file or similar.

A typical (very simple) HTTP page request might look like:

```
 telnet 216.92.143.231 80
 GET / HTTP/1.1
 host: www.rot13.com
```

(To which the server would then spit out the index page to [www.rot13.com](http://www.rot13.com)).  Note the third line - the web client tells the server which address it wants.  For HTTPS the process is significantly more complex due to https being wrapped around the connection and associated domain name - and why you should receive a warning of a potential security risk when you visit the site by IP address - but the idea is the same - the browser tells the server the site it wants, and the server responds.

It is entirely practical for a server to respond with whatever website it believes is appropriate - which is what is happening here.

Comment: Thanks, learn a lot.

Comment: This is helpful; what if I want to find a list of all domains associated with an IP?

Would there be a command I could put in similar to your telnet above that would display my options, say, if I did not know the URL for some mysterious reason?

Comment: There is no authirative way to get all the domains associated with an IP. If you have access to the server you can get the domains the server knows about by looking through the configs, and you can get a non-authorative list through doing web searches - but there is no remote command to dump this information.